# wcf :custom message inspector does not get wired up

Tags: c#, wcf

I have made a custom error handler on the service side:

```
 public class GlobalErrorHandler : Attribute, IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(
            ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
            ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
            Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
            BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            IErrorHandler errorHandler = new GlobalErrorHandler();

            foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;

                if (channelDispatcher != null)
                {
                    channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);

                }
            }
        }

        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(error.ToString());

            if (error is FaultException)
                return false; // Let WCF do normal processing
            else
                return true; // Fault message is already generated
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            if (error is FaultException)
            {
                // Let WCF do normal processing
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate fault message manually
                MessageFault messageFault = MessageFault.CreateFault(
                    new FaultCode("Sender"), new FaultReason(error.Message),
                    error, new NetDataContractSerializer());
                fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, null);
            }
        }

    }

    public class ErrorHandlerElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new GlobalErrorHandler();
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof (GlobalErrorHandler); }
        }
    }
```

I have defined a custom message inspector on the client side :

```
public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            if (reply.IsFault)
            {
                //do some processing
            }
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

I have a custom behaviour which  wire ups the message inspector :

```
public class NewtonsoftJsonBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
 public override void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime       clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageInspector());
        }
}
```

and this behaviour is applied programatically through a factory :

```
public class JsonWebServiceHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            var host =  base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
            //return host;
            //ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            //host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { HelpEnabled = true });     
            //return host;

            WebHttpBinding webBinding = new WebHttpBinding();

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, webBinding, "").Behaviors.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonBehavior());
            return host;
        }
    }
```

However when I debug and I generate a faultexception in the service, the globalerrorhandler gets called , but the debugger never steps into the message inspector.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

To create a Message Inspector on WCF service side, use an implementation of `IDispatchMessageInspector` instead of: `IClientMessageInspector`.

An example:

**Service:**

```
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9001/Message");

WebServiceHost svcWebHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service.Message), endpoint.Uri);

CustomServiceBehavior serviceBehavior = new CustomServiceBehavior();
svcWebHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);

Binding webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding();

ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = svcWebHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Service.IMessage), webHttpBinding, endpoint.Uri);

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
svcWebHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = svcWebHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

svcWebHost.Open();
```

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessage
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Model.TestResponse Test();
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
public class Message : IMessage
{
    public Model.TestResponse Test()
    {
        return new Model.TestResponse() { success = true, message = "OK!" };
    }
}
```

**CustomServiceBehavior implements IServiceBehavior:**

```
public class CustomServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        CustomEndpointBehavior endpointBehavior = new CustomEndpointBehavior();
        foreach (var endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
            endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(endpointBehavior);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {

    }
}
```

**CustomEndpointBehavior implements IEndpointBehavior**

```
public class CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        var inspector = new CustomDispatchMessageInspector();
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }
}
```

**CustomDispatchMessageInspector implements IDispatchMessageInspector**

```
public class CustomDispatchMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var httpResponse = ((HttpResponseMessageProperty)reply.Properties["httpResponse"]);
        httpResponse.Headers.Add("user-agent", "My Browser");
    }
}
```

This example is a WCF Self Hosted without configuration file (Configuring WCF Services in Code) that return a Json and send a custom header in HTTP Response (user-agent:My Browser).

To test this code:

1. Create a Windows Console Application
2. Insert the code (each
   block in one Class)
3. Run the applcation
4. Using browser open url:
   `http://localhost:9001/Message/Test`
5. The response is a Json:
   {"message":"OK!","success":true}
6. You can inspect the Response and
   see the custom header: "user-agent:My Browser"

Answer (score 0):

You only put your message inspector on the client side using `ApplyClientBehavior`. There is another method for the service side:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
{
  if (endpointDispatcher != null)
  {
    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageInspector());
  }
}
```

Comment: if I do as you suggested, I get The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None). error when calling the svc.

Comment: You will need to do some basic debugging. You can start with commenting out any logic in the message inspector to see if the problem is with the presence of a message inspector or with the message inspectors logic.